# calling Generic class in Bean class method gives error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac, java-6

I am trying to compile serviceBean.java file which imports one of my package, ledgement.java

In the serviceBean.java I added the below one line and it is not compiled it throws Cannot Find Symbol

```
ledgement ack = new ledgement(false,
                        e);

Here is the folder structure:

C:\working\src\java\com\test\tools\abc\mgmt\facade\service    

com/test/tools/abc/mgmt/facade/service/serviceBean.java

com/test/tools/abc/mgmt/util/ledgement.java
```

My ledgement class contains

```
 public class ledgement<T> extends Test {

        public enum EntityType implements Serializable {
            ART(1), ART1(2), RDER(3), LNE(4), 
            COUNT(5);
            private int typeId;

            EntityType(int id) {
                this.typeId = id;
            }

            /**
             * @return the entityClass
             */
            public int getTypeId() {
                return typeId;
            }

            /**
             * @param entityClass
             *            the entityClass to set
             */
            public void setTypeId(int id) {
                this.typeId = id;
            }
        } // Enum EntityType.

    public ledgement(boolean successFg) {
            this(successFg , null, null, null, null);
        }
   public ledgement(boolean sucessFg, Exception exp) {
        this(sucessFg, exp, null);
    }
```

it throws cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : constructor ledgement(boolean,java.lang.Exception
)

```
Not sure what is the issue by invoke the ledgment java class.
Please help.Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: Have you got `import com.test.tools.abc.mgmt.util.ledgement` in `ServiceBean` class?

Comment: Yes it is already imported

Comment: Is your `e` variable instantiated when you call it on the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra bracket in this line of code:
this(successFg) , null, null, null, null);

Comment: e is instantiated

Answer (score 0):

#### Starting point

The "ledgement" class itself – without the nested enum – looks like this:

```
public class ledgement<T> extends Test {
    public ledgement(boolean successFg) {
        this(successFg, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public ledgement(boolean sucessFg, Exception exp) {
        this(sucessFg, exp, null);
    }
}
```

and here's an empty "Test" class so that things will compile:

```
class Test {
}
```

#### Your observation

You stated that by doing something like below:

```
new ledgement(false, e);
```

you see an error like this:

```
[javac] symbol : constructor ledgement(boolean,java.lang.Exception)
```

This error is not reproducible. Below is a slight edit to your code, newing an exception (instead of using "e" which wasn't defined in your posted code). This line compiles fine:

```
new ledgement(false, new Exception());
```

#### The problem

Both of the constructors in turn refer to another constructor
which does not exist. This line:

```
this(successFg, null, null, null, null);
```

results in this compiler error:

```
no suitable constructor found for ledgement(boolean,<nulltype>,<nulltype>,<nulltype>,<nulltype>)
    constructor ledgement(boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor ledgement(boolean,java.lang.Exception) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

And this line:

```
this(sucessFg, exp, null);
```

results in this compiler error:

```
no suitable constructor found for ledgement(boolean,java.lang.Exception,<nulltype>)
    constructor ledgement(boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor ledgement(boolean,java.lang.Exception) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

#### Solution

Various things would probably help:

- Pay close attention to the compiler errors.
- Use declared constructors, matching the signatures – it's not allowed to call a constructor with several extra arguments (such as "null, null, null, null").
- Use an IDE such as IntelliJ – it will surface problems like this for you.
- If you're still seeing weird or strange things, do a clean build, remove previously compiled class files, etc. and try to reproduce the issue.